# Can some one help me identify these edge lines

Tags: mesh, modifiers, edges

So my problem is that i was making a low poly house and part of my workflow is to use the solidify modifier but after i applied it when i go and select or look at certain lines they very thick and also when i select one it goes black yellow-orange (or white) then black, its hard to discrib buts here's a image.

[image]

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Never mind, it's a crease i think, though i don't know if it should be there.

Comment: It's good you don't have a problem with it anymore, but I'm still curious as to what that is. Can you upload it to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so I can look at it?